# How to change the day of the week Logrotate shifts the file when configured weekly?

Tags: 12.04, cron, logrotate

I have following configuration which rotates all content of google folder weekly:

```
/var/log/google/*.log {
        create 0777 www-data www-data
        weekly
        missingok
        rotate 90
        compress
        delaycompress
        notifempty
        olddir /var/log/google/old
}
```

Now the thing is it does it rotation every Monday morning while I want to do the weekly rotation every Wednesday.

I was thinking to change the following entry in crontab:

```
47 6    * * 7   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.weekly )
```

But I am confused if this will work, because I could find `logrotate` in `/etc/cron.daily` and not in `/etc/cron.weekly`.

Is it possible to change files on Wednesday than Monday? If yes then how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the time of running weekly cron jobs won't help, for the reasons you stated.

Note what [the manpage of `logrotate`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/logrotate.8.html) says about `weekly` rotation:

```
   weekly Log  files  are  rotated if the current weekday is less than the
          weekday of the last rotation or if more than a week  has  passed
          since  the  last rotation. This is normally the same as rotating
          logs on the first day of  the  week,  but  it  works  better  if
          logrotate is not run every night.
```

That's why it tends to rotate on Mondays.

What you can do, is to run a special, separate instance of `logrotate` on Wednesdays, which only runs for the Google logs. For example, create `/etc/logrotate-google.conf`, containing the configuration you have specified, and create a cron job that runs on Wednesdays (as root, so use `/etc/crontab`, or `/etc/cron.d`):

```
46 6 * * 3 root logrotate /etc/logrotate-google.conf
```

Comment: Sunday is day 0, and so weekly log rotation is supposed to occur on Sunday.